# How To Simplify This PHP IF into MySQL WHERE?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I have PHP script works without problems, 
like this :

```
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
{
if (($row4['Username'] != 'root') && ($row4['ToUpline'] == 1)){
if (!(($row4['Username'] != $MyUsername) && ($row4['Private'] == 1))){

//some other scripts here...

}};
```

on the other hand, I already have WHERE conditon on MySQL command :

```
WHERE (NetworkTree.LeftNum <= $MyLeftNum AND NetworkTree.RightNum >= $MyRightNum) 
AND MyBlackList.HideWho IS NULL
```

how to combine these PHP conditions into 1 single SQL command so that I can remove PHP IF.
thanks...

Comment: `PHP if` is more faster than `mysql if`, and `if` in mysql is not for where condition

Comment: Sergey, why are you talking about MySQL `IF`?

Comment: You are supposed to do at least *some* research before asking a question; SO is not your developers sweatshop =p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE
  NetworkTree.LeftNum <= $MyLeftNum AND
  NetworkTree.RightNum >= $MyRightNum AND
  MyBlackList.HideWho IS NULL AND
  Username <> 'root' AND
  ToUpline = 1 AND
  NOT(Username <> 'myUsername' AND
      Private = 1)
```

How you fill in `'myUsername'` above depends on how you are executing your query. Since you are using the [outdated mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) functions you cannot use prepared statements, but you can use string concatenation or [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) (don't forget to escape using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)!). Here's how to do it with sprintf:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT ... WHERE ... NOT(Username <> '%s' ...)",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($username));
```

Comment: This will not work if $MyUsername contains alphabetic characters.

Comment: vearutop, it was actually meant as pseudo-SQL, but I can see the confusion. I've updated the question with more of the PHP side as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (NetworkTree.LeftNum <= $MyLeftNum AND NetworkTree.RightNum >= $MyRightNum) AND MyBlackList.HideWho IS NULL AND Username != 'root' AND ToUpLine = 1 AND NOT (Username != '$MyUsername' AND Private = 1)
```